# React bold type labels in array.map output

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a React component which is returning an array via an axios.get call to a JSON file. My output is an array of objects with this format:

```
{type: "tosca.resourceTypes.TPE", label: "BVI 610", value: "801070217_BVI610", id: "5bd4a1a4-f806-4355-bf34-1b4054c2881e"}
```

Here is the original get call:

```
axios.get('MasterData.json').then(response => {
       const fullNodes = response.data.graph.nodes;
       const result = Object.keys(fullNodes).map(key => ({
          ...fullNodes[key],
          id: key
    }));
```

What I need to do in the map function is output a div where the labels ("type", "label", "value", and id") are in bold type in a bulleted list but have not found an easy way to do this. Here is my map function:

```
{this.state.nodes.map((node, index) => (
        <li>{'LABEL GOES HERE IN BOLD}: {NODE GOES HERE</li>
    ))}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `label` property of `node`, either in a `span` with an appropriate class, or in a `strong` or `b`, and use `value` (presumably?) for the NODE GOES HERE bit:

```
{this.state.nodes.map((node, index) => (
    <li><strong>{node.label}</strong>: {node.value}</li>
))}
```

A few other notes:

- You'll need the `key` attribute (your best bet is to use the `id` from the node)
- You can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) if you like in the parameter list
- You don't need the `index` parameter if you're not going to use it

Taking those into account:

```
{this.state.nodes.map(({label, value, id}) => (
    <li key={id}><strong>{label}</strong>: {value}</li>
))}
```

(The `{label, value, id}` in the parameter is is the destructuring.)